# Is there a way to specify the argument in a function you want to reference?

Tags: python

I'm trying to write this code that prints a unit fraction when given a number(s). For instance `UnitFraction(3)` returns 1/3. This is fine however when I try to check for equivalence, I'm having trouble getting the right answer `UnitFraction(2) == UnitFraction(3,6)` should be `True` but I'm getting `False`.

```
class UnitFraction:
    def __init__(self, numerator=1, denominator=1):
        self.num = numerator
        self.den = denominator
        self.val = denominator/numerator

        if math.gcd(self.num, self.den) != 1:
            gcdt = math.gcd(self.num, self.den)
            self.num = int(self.num/gcdt)
            self.den = int(self.den/gcdt)

        elif self.den == 0:
            raise ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')

        elif self.den < 0:
            self.den = self.den*-1
            self.num = self.num*-1

    def __repr__(self):
        if self.den == 1:
            return str(self.num)
        else:
            return (f'{self.num}/{self.den}')

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.val == other.val

    def __add__(self, other):
        den1 = self.den
        den2 = other.den
        newdem = self.den*other.den
        return Fraction((self.den*other.num)+(other.den*self.num), newdem)

    def __sub__(self, other):
        den1 = self.den
        den2 = other.den
        newdem = self.den*other.den
        return Fraction(-(self.den*other.num)+(other.den*self.num), newdem)

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Fraction((self.num*other.num), (self.den*other.den))

    def __truediv__(self, other):
        newnum = self.num * other.den
        newnden = self.den * other.num
        return(Fraction(newnum, newnden))

    def plot(self):
        border_pts = np.array([(0, 0), (1, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (0, 0)])
        xcoords = border_pts[:, 0]
        ycoords = border_pts[:, 1]
        remainder = self.num % self.den
        for i in range(5):
            plt.plot(xcoords+i, ycoords, 'black')
        plt.axis('off')
        plt.axis('equal')
        plt.fill(xcoords*remainder, ycoords, color='blue')


UnitFraction(2) == UnitFraction(2,4)
```

Comment: Using floating point division for your fraction values seems like a bad idea since it involves round-off error. If you define a fraction class, you could do it in such a way that round-off error is avoided.

Comment: this is builtin ... [from fraction import fraction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html)

Comment: Make sure you keep track of which side of the fraction you're on. Your examples sometimes list the numerator first and sometimes the denominator (and sometimes they skip over one or the other). In your function, you declare `value` to be equal to the denominator divided by the numerator.

Comment: `self.val = denominator/numerator` This is backwards.

Comment: I don't understand how the question title has anything to do with what you're asking, and I don't understand why `UnitFraction(2) == UnitFraction(3,6)` should be `True`. Don't you mean `UnitFraction(6, 3)`? Wait - your intent is to make `UnitFraction(2)` represent `1/2`, rather than `2`? *Why*? If I used your code, I would be very surprised to read about that behaviour in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `*args` syntax to capture all of the arguments to `__init__`, then choose from there:

```py
class UnitFraction:
    def __init__(self, num, *args):
        if(len(args) == 0):
            self.numerator = 1
            self.denominator = num
        elif(len(args) == 1):
            self.numerator = num
            self.denominator = args[0]
        else
            raise TypeError("UnitFraction only takes 1 or 2 arguments")
```

It allows you to have a variable number of arguments, without losing the protection from multiple parameters being passed.

Comment: You cannot `raise` a string in Python; write `raise Error(...)` instead, or you could use `TypeError` in this case.